# cannot import texthero in python

Tags: python, import, nlp

I am trying to import and use the texthero module in python and keep getting an error message.

code is simply `import texthero as hero`

there is a really long error message

```
[nltk_data] Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A
[nltk_data]     connection attempt failed because the connected party
[nltk_data]     did not properly respond after a period of time, or
[nltk_data]     established connection failed because connected host
[nltk_data]     has failed to respond>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\texthero\stopwords.py in <module>()
     13     # If not present, download 'en_core_web_sm'
---> 14     spacy_model = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
     15 except OSError:

C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py in load(name, **overrides)
     29         warnings.warn(Warnings.W001.format(path=depr_path), DeprecationWarning)
---> 30     return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
     31 

C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\spacy\util.py in load_model(name, **overrides)
    174         return load_model_from_path(name, **overrides)
--> 175     raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
    176 

OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    159             conn = connection.create_connection(
--> 160                 (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
    161             )

C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     83     if err is not None:
---> 84         raise err
     85 

C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     73                 sock.bind(source_address)
---> 74             sock.connect(sa)
     75             return sock

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    676                 headers=headers,
--> 677                 chunked=chunked,
    678             )

C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    380         try:
--> 381             self._validate_conn(conn)
    382         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
    977         if not getattr(conn, "sock", None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
--> 978             conn.connect()
    979 

C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    308         # Add certificate verification
--> 309         conn = self._new_conn()
    310         hostname = self.host

C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    171             raise NewConnectionError(
--> 172                 self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
    173             )

NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000019860160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    726             retries = retries.increment(
--> 727                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
    728             )

C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    438         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 439             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    440 

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /explosion/spacy-models/master/shortcuts-v2.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000019860160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a19be4912cd0> in <module>()
----> 1 import texthero as hero
      2 

C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\texthero\__init__.py in <module>()
      4 
      5 """
----> 6 from . import preprocessing
      7 from .preprocessing import *
      8 

C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\texthero\preprocessing.py in <module>()
     12 from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer, SnowballStemmer
     13 
---> 14 from texthero import stopwords as _stopwords
     15 
     16 from typing import List, Callable

C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\texthero\stopwords.py in <module>()
     16     from spacy.cli.download import download as spacy_download
     17 
---> 18     spacy_download("en_core_web_sm")
     19 
     20 from spacy.lang.en import stop_words as spacy_en_stopwords

C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\spacy\cli\download.py in download(model, direct, *pip_args)
     42         dl = download_model(dl_tpl.format(m=model_name, v=version), pip_args)
     43     else:
---> 44         shortcuts = get_json(about.__shortcuts__, "available shortcuts")
     45         model_name = shortcuts.get(model, model)
     46         compatibility = get_compatibility()

C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\spacy\cli\download.py in get_json(url, desc)
     93 
     94 def get_json(url, desc):
---> 95     r = requests.get(url)
     96     if r.status_code != 200:
     97         msg.fail(

C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     74 
     75     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 76     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     77 
     78 

C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     59     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     60     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 61         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     62 
     63 

C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    528         }
    529         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 530         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    531 
    532         return resp

C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    641 
    642         # Send the request
--> 643         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 
--> 516             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    517 
    518         except ClosedPoolError as e:

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /explosion/spacy-models/master/shortcuts-v2.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000019860160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))
```

So it seems not to be able to open the stopwords file. I have checked the data folders and it is present.

when it can't find it it then tries to find the spacy file 'en_core_web_sm'
I cannot find this in the folders although spacy is there.

I then get a time out as it can't find the file.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling spacy and texthero and updating both.

I have tired installing en_core_web_sm and the other versions

e.g. using code:

```
!pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0.tar.gz
```

and

```
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

I have tried reinstalling/updating nltk

I have run in Jupyter notebook and in Python and CMD (as admin). all with the same error.

I've tried both python commands and pip to do the above installs etc.

I really don't know what else to try

any ideas?

thanks

Mizz

Comment: `So it seems not to be able to DOWNLOAD the stopwords file.` ftfy. The last line tells you the occured error. Can't help you further. On the github page there is an issue to prevent it from downloading the stopwords, although no mention of a connectionerror. (https://github.com/jbesomi/texthero/issues/193)

Comment: You maybe have some connection problems, behind a firewall or something else? Hard to tell. This is working for me, at least: `python3.6 -m venv venv && source venv/bin/activate && pip install texthero spacy && python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm && python -c "import texthero as hero; print('okay')"`

Comment: @colidyre thanks for your answer. what does venv venv && source venv/bin/activate mean/do? i get a syntax error if i run as is. i think i may have an environment issue. it seems to be looking for text hero in the wrong environment but i'm not certain that's right. i've spent so many hours going round in circles i can't get anything straight now

Comment: ok so not an environment issue. i've tried to import it from the live environment and i get the exact same issues

Comment: @MizzH see https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html for creating a virtual environment, so that you can manage different dependencies for different projects.